# Почему данные автоматически отправляются в базу данных

Tags: php, html, база-данных

при перезагрузке страницы данные автоматически отправляются в базу данных(если поля пустые, то отправляются пустые строки)

**register.php:**

```
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $login = $_POST['login'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
    if(isset($email) && isset($login) && isset($password))
    {
        $STH = $DBH->query("INSERT INTO data(email,login,password) VALUES('$email','$login','$password')");
    }
}
```

**connection.php:**

```
<?
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "data";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);

try {   
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass, $options); 
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}  
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
}
```

**форма:**

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
        <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="login">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" name="button">
    </form>
```

как это исправить?

Comment: Проверка `if(isset($email) && isset($login) && isset($password))` **абсолютно** бессмысленная. оператор isset проверяет, существует ли переменная. Но ты все три переменных создал двумя строчками выше. То есть эта проверка **всегда** будет возвращать true

Comment: @Ипатьев, но ведь isset(null) — false

Comment: `при перезагрузке страницы`, вообще-то браузер предупреждает. что «данные будут отправлены заново» при перезагрузке POST

Comment: @vp_arth хм да верно. что-то я настолько привык к своему коду, где нотис транслируется в исключение, что для меня присвоение пременной несуществующего значения в принципе не сработает. а так получается да - своя логика в этом коде есть.

Answer (score 1):

Почему форма отправляется при обновлении?

Обновление страницы повторяет последний запрос, т.е. если последним была отпрака формы(`POST`), то браузер честно отправит запрос ещё раз.

Как избежать?

Можно отдавать редирект на ту же страницу, т.к. при редиректе будет уже `GET` запрос. Так же, можно отправить форму на js.

Почему пропускается проверка `isset($email) /* AND ... */`?

Поля, если не были заполнены, но указаны в форме, содержат пустую строку. Т.к `isset($var)` это аналог `$var !== null`, то ваша проверка будет пропускаться т.к. идёт сравнение `"" !== null`.

Как избежать?

Можно проверять просто как `if($email){}`, т.к. `"" == false` и `null == false`([внмание на количество](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php) `=`). Но лучше явно проверить на длину и содержание

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте редирект после обработки формы.

```
if (
    !empty($_POST['email'])
    && !empty($_POST['login'])
    && !empty($_POST['password'])
) {
    // Делаем какие-то действия с данными из формы
    // Далее, переадресуем пользователя на другую страницу
    header('Location: /otherPage.php');
} else {
    throw new Exception('Ой, ошибочка вышла!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что кнопка обновить в браузере, повторяет последнее выполненное действие, в вашем случае это отправка формы, вот она и отправляет пустые данные, вам правильно советуют с редиректом, либо сделайте в register.php проверку что бы данные были не пустые